# Can the MX51 support usb 3.0?

Tags: usb, hardware, cpu, usb-flash-drive

I have a device that is run by a MX51 cpu what I would like to know are:

what steps to take to replace an sd slot with mini usb 3.0 thumb drives? This means physically remove the hardware and install a usb 3.0 port in place of the SD slot.

What drivers would i need to install into the OS on the device?

What else do i need to know hardware men?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the  http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX515 from the block diagram click on Block pic. You can see this only support USB2.0